# Using Android SDK to make menu driven game

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-scrollview, android-gridlayout

I'm working on an Android game and at the moment I'm using libgdx using the table layout.

I would like to give Android SDK a try since my game is menu driven and the Android API seems to have a lot of the widgets that I need for my game.

One of my screen is divided into 4 areas (Landscape orientation).

I would like area 1 to span 1 column and be scroll-able like a list view but display a list of custom widgets (Very similar to a contact card where there is picture and right next to it there is information displayed).

I would like area 2 to span 2 columns and it will be similar to area 1 but the widget class is different than the widget used in area 1.

I would like area 3 to span 2 columns and it will be similar to the android home screen where there is a grid full of icons that can be scrolled up and down.

And finally I would like area 4 to span one column and be split into 3 rows to hold 3 different unique widgets.

I would like for all the screen space to be used so that on higher screen the content gets stretched and in smaller screen it gets stretched down.

Something like this (Hopefully it will display properly):

----------------------------
 | == | ==== | ++++ | [] |   
 | == | ==== | ++++ | [] |   
 | == | ==== | ++++ | [] |   
 ----------------------------

Which layout will allow me to accomplish this? I was thinking GridLayout or TableLayout.

Will Android API allow me to "theme" or "style" the widgets to provided an user interface that is consistent across multiple android versions?

I know Android lets me "theme" an activity and "style" widgets but will that cause the layout to break or android will scale my custom images? I'm planning on having my images split by screen density (if that makes sense).

If someone could point me in the right direction or share their experience with developing a game for Android using Android APIs instead of a game engine or framework that would be great.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you tried anything or looked at other examples of the different layouts yet?

Comment: @jblasco Yes I have. I have been experimenting with TableLayout because it was what felt natural coming from libgdx but I could not get it to work as expected or wanted. I have been reading the Android API documentation and also searching in Google for specific topics but still have not found an example to do what I want to do. Thank you.